# Upload an image after 64-bit encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to upload an image on a server. I encode to 64-bit then I post. I am using this code:

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://boomagift.ramansingla.com/userpicture.php?email=sonal@gmail.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *req=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
// [req setValue:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=*****" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postBody=[NSMutableData data];
NSString *boundary=@"*****";


[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *this=[pickedImageData base64EncodedString];

[postBody appendData: [this dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[req setHTTPBody:postBody];


NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;
        NSError *error=[[NSError alloc] init];

NSData *responseData;
    responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseData);
    if(responseData&&[responseData length])
    {

        NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"hello");
    }
```

Comment: Please, explain what is your problem with this code, whether you get an error, etc. See [ask].

Comment: i m not geeting response data it print hello. i want  geeting data 0 or 1.

Comment: If something fails with an error you should always check and post an error you receive.

Comment: You mean Base64? If so, why?

Comment: yes i want encoded base 64

Comment: Did you have a problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @HotLicks this show null response

Comment: And no `error` value????

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSArray *)getResizedUImage:(UIImage *)getImage otherValueOne:(float)newWidth otherValueSecond:(float)newHeight
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newWidth, newHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 1);
    [getImage drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSArray *loadImageDateArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    UIImage *imageConvert = img;
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageConvert, 0.8);
    NSString *base64String = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    loadImageDateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:base64String];
    return loadImageDateArray;
}
```

This code part return base 64 try this
I update my answer use this function, this function return base 64